Engines, 2nd Law
Suppose we have an engine which extracts heat from a source, but the source is not a "reservoir", per se.
Now, Kelvin Statement forbids the existence of engines whose only final result is transformation into work, heat absorbed from a single temperature source.
However, let's have a source whose temp. changes with time
[not necessarily because heat was absorbed, some other reason. Basically, the source acts like a reservoir for a short period of time, then it's temperature is changed. Note that this "time scales" are very short, but finite nonetheless!]
Now, can we construct an engine which can extract all heat and convert it into work. Because it doesn't violate the Kelvin Statement.
If yes, please give me a "mental model"

In this and your prior post you talk about heat engines when you should be talking about heat engine operating in a cycle. Regardless of whether or not the heat source is a single "reservoir", you can't have a heat engine that produces net work over a cycle without having some heat transferred out of the system. That precludes the possibility of converting all the heat input to net work in a cycle.

It does not matter whether the heat source/heat sink is a reservoir or shmeservoir, what matters is the temperature at which entropy enters the engine and the temperature at which at least that much entropy leaves the engine so that the cycle can be completed. By a "cycle" is meant a thermodynamic process during which the engine is returned to its original state, and then you can evaluate the amount of work produced per cycle versus the amount of net thermal energy received with which the full cycle produced said work.


Now, Kelvin Statement forbids the existence of engines whose only
final result is transformation into work, heat absorbed from a single
temperature source.

The issue is not whether the source involves a single temperature. It's the engine cannot transfer heat with single heat source and produce net work in a cycle. Sometime during the cycle heat must be rejected to a lower temperature heat source in order to complete the cycle and produce net work.

Now, can we construct an engine which can extract all heat and convert
it into work. Because it doesn't violate the Kelvin Statement.

Not in a cycle. Theoretically all heat from the hot reservoir is converted to work in the reversible isothermal expansion process of the Carnot cycle. But in order to complete the cycle some heat must be rejected to the cold reservoir during the reversible isothermal compression.
As an exercise, try and come up with any cycle on a PV diagram where net work, which is the area enclosed by the cycle, is produced without some heat leaving the system.
Hope this helps.
